# How to implement master/detail components without hierarchical routes?

Tags: angular, routes

I am trying to implement the following things together.

an index page with route `/items` (plural). This page is scrollable.

on clicking on the individual items I want to show a detail page but the route has to be `/item/:id` (singular).

There is a back button detail page. On clicking, it should go back to `/items` but should remain on the same scroll position it left.

I thought of implementing it as a master detail. But My routes are not in the hierarchy?

How should I handle this?

I can do `/items and /items/:id` (Both plural)

Or `/item and /item/:id` (Both singular)

But I want do it one singular and one plural

Route config files

app-routing.ts

```
{
    path: 'items',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/items/items.module').then(m => m.ItemsModule),
    data: { animation: 'Items'}
  },
  {
    path: 'item',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/Item/Item.module').then(m => m.ItemModule),
    data: { animation: 'Item', type: 'Item'}
  },
```

Item routing config.

```
[{
  path: ':id',
  component: ItemComponent,
  resolve: {
    item: ItemResolverService
  },
  runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange'
}]
```

Comment: are you using lazy loading routes? can you please share your current route config

Comment: edited in the post

Answer (score 0):

You should create a single top level lazy loaded route like so:

```
{
  path: 'my-items',
  loadChildren: () => import('./pages/my-items/my-items.module').then(m => m.MyItemsModule)
}
```

Then create a new routing module with Angular CLI like so:

```
ng generate module pages/my-items/my-items --routing=true
```

This will create a route module with 2 module files. One of the module files contains the child routes for the my-items route.

In this module file you should define your child routes like so:

```
[
  {
    path: 'items',
    component: ItemsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'item/:id',
    component: ItemComponent
  }
]
```

You will obviously need to create these 2 components (ItemsComponent and ItemComponent) and they should be nested within the module folder in which they are used. Again you can use the Angular CLI to generate these components (and if you do and if they are nested as stated, it should automatically declare them in the correct module).

```
ng generate component path/component-name
```

OR

```
ng g c path/component-name
```

You can access these routes on:

```
/my-items/items
```

AND

```
/my-items/item/ITEM_ID
```

SCROLLING:

To maintain the scroll position when the user clicks BACK:

In the master view use:

```
@ViewChild('scrollableEl ') scrollableEl: ElementRef;
```

And in your HTML add `#scrollableEl` to the scrollable element.

You now have a handle on the scrollable element.

Then do something like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  const scrollEl: HTMLElement = this.scrollableEl.nativeElement;
  // set last known scroll top value when master view loads
  const strScrollTop: string = sessionStorage.getItem('scrollTop');
  const scrollTop: number = strScrollTop ? parseInt(strScrollTop, 10) : 0;
  scrollEl.scrollTop = scrollTop;
  // keep track of the last known scroll position
  scrollEl.onscroll = () => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('scrollTop', scrollEl.scrollTop);
  };
}
```

You do not need to add any code to your detail view.

This solution basically keeps track of the last known scroll position in sessionStorage. When the master component loads it scrolls the list to that last known scroll position. My code is not tested so there may be an error or 2 here or there but you should get the idea.

EXAMPLE SETINTERVAL CLEVER CODE AS PER COMMENT

In case your scroll element is not ready on page load, this is some example code to grab an element as soon as its ready. It always clears the interval as soon as it can. You will need to tailor this code to meet your needs.

```
@ViewChild('summaries') summaries: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.doScroll();
}

@HostListener('window:resize')
onResize(): void {
  this.doScroll();
}

private doScroll(): void {
  this.whenElementReady('summaries').then((el: HTMLElement) => {
    if (el) {
      // change this to the scrollTop value that you need
      el.scrollTop = 0;
    }
  });
}

private whenElementReady(elementName: string): Promise<HTMLElement> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
  // will keep trying for 30 seconds
    const maxAttempts = 300;
    let attempts = 0;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const el: HTMLElement = this[elementName]?.nativeElement;
      if (el) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        resolve(el);
      } else if (attempts > maxAttempts) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        resolve(null);
      }
      attempts++;
    }, 100);
  });
}
```

Comment: It is not just the routine stuff.
I also want to preserve the scroll position when the user goes from child to parent.
That's why I am trying to implement it as master-detail-like behavior where when the child route is destroyed, the parent remains as it is.

In the above case, on going back to items from /item/:id the page is scrolled to the top which is not so good experience for me.

Comment: I've just added a SCROLLING section to my answer

Comment: master-detail only works as you describe where the master and detail are rendered together on the same view - e.g. master on LHS and detail on RHS - where this is not the case the solution I have outlined is needed

Comment: I marked my routes 'forward', 'backward' by passing route parameters
Saved scroll position for forward and restored the same for backward.
It works good but when the user goes back, route animation and scroll happen simultaneously. 
Still trying my best to make this work.

Comment: if you are basically saying its a bit jerky on page load when the scroll suddenly jumps down then have you thought about using an animation such as fading the page in to hide the jerkiness - if you set up your route config as I suggested then ngOnInit and ngAfterViewInit should be called each time you visit the master view - put your scroll code in ngAfterViewInit. If your scroll element is not  ready in time then use a setTimeout or setInterval - you can make this clever - Ive pasted some example clever setInterval in my answer in case it helps

Comment: Also, if you want a smooth scroll animation (instead of the scroll instantly jumping to the scrollTop position you set) then use this css ... scroll-behavior: smooth; ... this should be added to the element that has the scrollbar